# Redirecting a dynamic page to a new dynamic page

Tags: .htaccess

My site has the following url structure:

```
/shoe/view/3
/shoe/view/5
/shoe/view/86
/shoe/view/124
```

I want to 301 redirect everything using htaccess to a new structure like so:

```
/item/3
/item/5
/item/86
/item/124
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
RedirectMatch 301 \/shoe\/view\/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/item/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^shoe/view/(.*)$ /item/$1 [R=301]
```